# Appending two arrays in Python

Tags: python, numpy, append

I am trying to append two numpy arrays `A` and `J[0]` using `np.concatenate` but there is an error. I also present the expected output.

```
import numpy as np

A=np.array([ 1,  3,  5,  7,  9, 10, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 18, 20, 21, 22, 23])

J=[[4, 6, 8, 11, 17, 19]]
J=np.array(J)
T=np.concatenate(A,J[0],axis=1)
```

The error is

```
in <module>
    T=np.concatenate(A,J[0],axis=1)

  File "<__array_function__ internals>", line 4, in concatenate

TypeError: concatenate() got multiple values for argument 'axis'
```

The expected output is

```
array([ 1,  3,  4, 5,  6, 7,  8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23])
```

Comment: reread the `np.concatenate` docs!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
T = np.sort(np.concatenate((A, J[0])))
```